# How to get value for next same key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this when printed:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [sku] => exp_pokemonketchup_001
        [_id] =>   539be6740478ca09233ac71e
        [__v] => 0
        [type] => 3
        [status] => 1
        [_create_date] => 2014-06-14T06:06:44.365Z
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [sku] => exp_onepiecegobble_001
        [_id] => 539be6710478ca09233ac71c
        [__v] => 0
        [type] => 3
        [status] => 1
        [_create_date] => 2014-06-14T06:06:41.110Z
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [sku] => exp_sailormoongiggle_001
        [_id] => 539be66d0478ca09233ac717
        [__v] => 0
        [type] => 3
        [status] => 1
        [_create_date] => 2014-06-14T06:06:37.633Z
    )
)
```

I'm trying to get the `sku` and corresponding value for the subsequent `sku` during a `foreach` loop. In other words, I’m looping through the array, echoing the first sku, which is `exp_pokemonketchup_001`.

Now I also need to echo out the next `sku` which is `exp_onepiecegobble_001` but before the loop continues to that part of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The above can be sorted using an inbuilt PHP function get_object_vars();
In the given array i have tried recreating the array using just one field.
Please see the below code.

    `<?php
    $obj = array((object) array('sku' => 'exp_pokemonketchup_001'),
          (object) array('sku' => 'exp_onepiecegobble_001')
          );
         foreach($obj as $k => $v){
            $objDetails =get_object_vars($v);
            print_r($objDetails['sku']);
           }
    ?>`

Comment: get_object_vars function gets it converted to array in php.[get_object_vars()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assuming `$array` is your current array of objects

```
$array_size = count($array); 

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {

    // echo current sku
    echo $val->sku;     

    // If not the last object, echo next sku       
    if ($key < $array_size-1) {
        echo $array[$key+1]->sku; 
    }

}
```